# HTML: cell padding and spacing in selected row or column

Tags: html, row, cell

i just started learning in HTML.
I'm having a problem in cell padding and spacing...
the one that i created have a cell padding and spacing on all row... is it possible to have a cell spacing and padding in the 1st row but not in the 2nd row?
`

```
    </td>
<tr>
    <td width="250" height="500">

    </td>
    <td width="750">

    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" height="75">

    </td>
</tr>
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to wrap the content you want to edit in a  and add css properties like for example: 
Take a look at this div and style combination, it gets kinda useful sometimes. You can make the particular elements special even when they are in a table with constant style.
You can even add this style attribute to the / tags themselves. Maybe what you're looking for.

Comment: yes that's what I need...but, can I use div in a table?

Comment: Sure but not like instead of tr or td, you need to use it inside them. And as I suggested you can use css style stuff for the td and tr themselves and even make them special with id or class.

Comment: but what if in this table:

<table border="10">
 <tr>
  <td colspan="2" height="200">
  1st
  </td>
 <tr>
  <td width="250" height="500">
   2nd
  </td>
  <td width="750">
   3rd
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="2" height="75">
   4th
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>

i dont want cell space between 2nd and 3rd and 4th?

Comment: @BONBON what exactly do you mean by cellspace? I see it without any spaces, not sure what you mean

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add padding to each **TD** not **TR**
But spacing between cells only for the whole **TABLE**

The Attribute padding is the response about cell padding

```
<table border="1" style="border-spacing:2px;">
        <tr>
            <td width="250" height="500" style="padding:5px;">One</td>
            <td width="750" style="padding:5px;">Two</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" height="75">Three</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```